# Chaining Javascript Constructors

Tags: javascript, constructor-chaining

I've Googled this like crazy, and I still don't understand.

If I set up child and parent objects like the following:

```
var Child = function(name, toy)
{
    this.toy = toy;
    Parent.call(this, name);
}

var Parent = function(name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

//Child.prototype = new Parent();
```

I do **not** need to uncomment the above line so as to be able to get the following result:

```
var bobby = new Child("Robert", "Lego");
document.write(bobby.name + " " + bobby.toy);

//Result: Robert Lego
```

My (probably incorrect) understanding is that the line

```
Child.prototype = new Parent();
```

sets the prototype of what is created by the Child constructor to be what is created by the Parent constructor. Hence, without this line, the line

```
Parent.call(this, name);
```

(which I believe calls the Parent constructor, setting the this context to Child, and passes in name) shouldn't actually work.

What is wrong with my understanding?

Thanks in advance for any help!   :)

Comment: Why don't you believe `Parent.call(this, name);` should work? It is just calling the `Parent` function, which you define.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't know that a function is a constructor. It's only treated as one when you call it using the `new` keyword. If you were to call it without `new`, it would behave differently.

`Parent.call(this, name)` simply calls `Parent` as a regular function, using the newly constructed `Child` (because you used the `new` keyword when you constructed a Child) as its `this`.

So all your function `parent` does in this case is assign the name to the object that it received. In this case, the `Child` that you just constructed.

Compare your Child to this:

```
var Child = function(name, toy)
{
    var child = new Parent(name);
    child.toy = toy;
    return child;
}
```

Here, the child function is using `Parent` as a constructor.

Comment: That's not 100% true to say "JS doesn't know a function is a constructor". First of all, the interpreter internally register (by standard, not implementation-factor) functions with a Constructible property. Second, only functions created normally (eg not with the Shorthand notation, or Arrow Functions, as opposed to Normal notation) are constructible. It's true that only when you use 'new', a constructible function is treated as a constructor, but it's not the case for ANY function

Comment: @Reflection that's true now, but when I wrote this answer in 2013, things were different. For example, there were no arrow functions yet.